# Null object reference after I remove a view

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

So I am trying to show a certien depending on what item is selected in the spinner. But when i remove a view from the original layout replace it then try to reference it in any way it gives me a null object reference.

Code:

```
if(subjectSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("All")){

                allSelected();

            } else {

                if(taskList == null){
                    Log.i("SQL", "task list id null");
                    taskList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.tasks_list);
                }

//error points at this line
                if(taskList.getParent() == null){

                    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);

                    baseView.removeAllViews();

                    baseView.addView(appBarLayout);
                    baseView.addView(subjectSpinner);
                    baseView.addView(taskList);
                    baseView.addView(textView);

                }
```

The allSelected() method:

```
void allSelected (){
    subjectSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.tasks_list_spinner);
    taskList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.tasks_list);
    baseView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_view_tasks);

    baseView.removeView(taskList);

    ScrollView           scrollView    = new ScrollView(getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout         linearLayout  = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    List <TextView>      subjectText   = new ArrayList <>();
    List <RecyclerView>  recyclerViews = new ArrayList <>();
    List <CustomAdaptor> adaptor       = new ArrayList <>();

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams scrollViewParams =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    scrollViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.textView10);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

PS. these are not the full code but I am doing nothing else with the taskList recyclerView outside of these snippets.

Logcat:

```
 Process: com.example.user.timetable_test, PID: 12685
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewParent android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.getParent()' on a null object reference
     at com.example.user.timetable_test.ViewTasks$1.onItemSelected(ViewTasks.java:225)
     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:1165)
     at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:1154)
     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:59)
     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:1121)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)

                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

The .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_view_tasks"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.timetable_test.ViewTasks"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_viewTasks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tasks_list_spinner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar_viewTasks" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/subject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar_viewTasks" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tasks_list"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So does someone know why am I getting this error and how to fix it?

BTW this is not a duplicate of *What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?*. Yes it is about null pointer exception, but it doesn't ask **what** is a null pointer exception, but rather *how did I get a null pointer exception in this code?*

Since I am editing the question and can't post an answer, let me say that I fixed the error by not removing the views, instead making them invisible. It is a work around and not really a *fix*. If you have a similar problem, hope this helps :)

Comment: Your taskList etc. are class variables? Why are you assigning them every time you change the spinner selection?

Comment: @kristyna I thought that I need to reassign them every time, hence the null error.

Comment: Try to assign these vies only once. I see no reason why to assign them again and again... Maybe this should help you with that nullpointer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that even if the null check fails for `tasklist` you still call `getParent` for it. You should wrap the rest of the code inside `else` for the `if (tasklist ==null)` part like this:

```
if(subjectSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("All")){

                allSelected();

            } else {

                if(taskList == null){
                    Log.i("SQL", "task list id null");
                    taskList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.tasks_list);
                }

//add else here
               else{
                if(taskList.getParent() == null){

                    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);

                    baseView.removeAllViews();

                    baseView.addView(appBarLayout);
                    baseView.addView(subjectSpinner);
                    baseView.addView(taskList);
                    baseView.addView(textView);

                }
        }
```

Comment: wouldn't that skip `baseView.removeAllViews();` if taskList was null?

Comment: yes it would.. But the reason your exception was occurring was because it was trying to evaluate `getParent` for a null object. Also looking at your layout xml the parent of the RecyclerView is baseView so if it is null then calling `removeAllViews` inside that block doesn't make sense either

Comment: it is because there are other views inside the layout, added in code, that i want to remove them to add the recycler view on a clean slate. On another point, I will try, instead of removing the recycler view, to change the visibility depending on whether I want it or not.

Comment: It would be better if you change visibility instead of removing views since redrawing them is expensive and should be avoided i

Answer (score 0):

The error code says:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewParent android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.getParent()' on a null object reference
```

Which means `taskList` is `null`.

Possible mistake in your code:

- Check setContentView(R.layout.your_layout) or inflated layout - is tasks_list id really in your_layout.xml or inflated layout?

Comment: I assume you are asking me if the referenced id is in the inflated layout, I posted an edit giving the .xml file of the layout